# Проблема с media в pythonanywhere

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

pythonanywhere не может найти файлы в папке media
[image]

Но этот файл есть!
[image]

roots в  settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/dimabytes/my-first-blog/static'

MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/dimabytes/my-first-blog/media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

web на pythonanywhere

[image]